# how to store text file information into my sql database

Tags: mysql, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures, mod-perl

> this is my text file

```
StudentId Name  Dept address     city
1         Chellappa   CSE 22 xx-colony 2nd street   coimbatore
2         Vijay        IT 23 yy colony  coimbatore
```

In this file (22 xx-colony 2nd street) and (23 yy colony) is address to store in database address column

```
use DBI;
use strict;

my $driver = "mysql"; 
my $database = "TESTDB";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "1234";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $query = 'INSERT INTO student (StudentId,Name,Dept,address,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr();

open my $fh, "<", "text.txt" or die $!;
 <$fh>;  #skip header

  while (<$fh>)
 {
    chomp;
    my @vals = split; 

    $sth->execute(@vals);
 }
close $fh;
```

this code is doesn't work properly for that text file anyone can help me

Comment: Is that tab separated data? Or fixed width? Or no real format at all? You can't split on whitespace if you have whitespace inside the fields.

Comment: when i run this programme following error was occur DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 8 bind variables when 4 are needed

Comment: What is the output of `hexdump -C textfile`?

Comment: 0000000   S   t   u   d   e   n   t   I   D       N   a   m   e       D
0000010   e   p   t  \n   8       C   h   e   l   l   a   p   p   a    
0000020   T   c   h       I   T  \n   9       V   i   j   a   y       K
0000030   r   i   s   h       C   S   E  \n   1   0       A   A   A    
0000040   B   B       E   C   E  \n                                    
0000047

Comment: That does not appear to match the text given in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 8 bind variables when 4 are
>   needed

That error is not generated by the code that you have shown us. Your code contains this:

```
my $query = 'INSERT INTO student (StudentId,Name,Dept,address,city) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
```

That SQL query contains five bind points, not four. It's always important to be accurate when reporting these things.

Anyway, the important thing is that the number of bind points is different to the number of values you pass to `execute()`. And it's pretty simple to see where that problem comes from.

Your first data line is this:

```
1         Chellappa   CSE 22 xx-colony 2nd street   coimbatore
```

And you split that data into the `@vals` array with this code:

```
my @vals = split;
```

With no arguments, `split()` splits `$_` on whitespace (you can [read the documentation online](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)).

So, after running that code on that data, you'll end up with eight values in `@vals`. Those values are:

```
1, Chellappa, CSE, 22, xx-colony, 2nd, street, coimbatore
```

So it's clear that your simple `split()` isn't processing your data in the way that you expect. You'll need to come up with a more sophisticated way to extract your five expected data items from your input record.

Unfortunately, you don't give us any detail on how your input file is structured, so we can't give you any more help on how to fix your problem.

**Update:** Guessing at what you might want here, the update statement could become something like:

```
$sth->update(@vals[0 .. 2], join ' ', @vals[3..6], $vals[7]);
```

But I have no idea how well that will work with other lines of data that might have the whitespace in other places.

Comment: In my question is how to join 4 array values such as  (22, xx-colony ,2nd ,street) into single array value. i.e this contain 4 strings 22, xx-colony, 2nd, street is converted(join) into single string 22 xx-colony 2nd street

Comment: No, that's not in your question, is it? :-) But you can use `join()`. Something like `join ' ', @vals[3..6]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using join(). Since you have all the values separated by space you are getting this problem. If your file is created by you then you can just add comma separated values like (1, Chellappa, CSE, 22 xx-colony 2nd street,coimbatore). This will help you to fetch all the data using split as follows
**split(',',)**.